# What's the correct template technology in typo3?

Tags: typo3, typoscript, fluid

I start a new website and I want to learn/use TYPO3. I read much about normal typoscript templating with static html files, templatevoila and fluid. But what is the correct way to implement the design from the ui team in TYPO3?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- Fluid is the latest and greatest way to do templating in TYPO3.
- Templavoila is dead
- Marker-based templating with TypoScript is similar to fluid, but much more limited.

Answer (score 3):

While a lot of the more technical HTML (body tags, footer scripts, stylesheets, etc) are usually set via TypoScript the actual templates for content elements should be written using Fluid Templates, Partials and Layouts. Take a look at the sysext "fluid_styled_content".

Answer (score 1):

The flexibility of TYPO3 allows you here many possibilities . Classic and rather old school working with markers while Fluidtemplating has many design options provides .
But Grid element , DCE or fluid Styled Content or MASK offer their benefits .

Ultimately probably a matter of taste .